# How to select dates greater than current using date_format

Tags: mysql

I have my records in mysql stored with a datetime column. I would like to get records that are greater than the current date.

example:
select * from MY_TABLE WHERE mytime is greater than today.

I know I need to use DATE_FORMAT but not sure how to construct the query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to do:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE mytime > NOW()
```